# None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices?

Tags: ios, xcode

We have a company account .
We have created the `developer and distribution provisioning` files, and drag them into Xcode.

When we try to `code sign` for distribution, we choose the `release` to be :

```
iPhone distribution:companyName
```

We always get this error when trying to put the app on real iPhone ( this iPhone is registered in the dev center and included in the dev provisioning file! ):

```
None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices:myDevice
```

But they Are include this device.

Comment: "we choose the release to be" ... "included in the dev provisioning file", please confirm the device to be included into the distribution profile as you seem to be trying to use it.

Comment: When you create a distribution file, you dont add devices. At least i didn't see this in the options when creating it on the dev center.  Only when creating development provisioning you have the option to add devices.

Comment: So you are trying to compile app from xcode on device using distribution profile?

Comment: Depending on the profile type you might need to select the included devices, based on the error message I believe you don't have an enterprise account and your AdHoc profiles don't have the device you are trying to use.

Comment: No its not an enterprise account. So what else should i do to approve my device other than creating distribution file? Its already included in the dev file. When i try to run he says he will fix the problem and than the code signing turns from distribution to dev and the error disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a provisioning profile created for Ad Hoc Deployment to solve this issue:

1. Create an Archive: Xcode->Product->Archive
2. After the Archive is created: Export (pane on the right) -> Save for Ad Hoc Deployment -> Follow through the process; whether you save the .ipa file in the end is irrelevant
3. Go back to "Build Settings" and set "Code Signing Identity" for Release to "iOS Distribution", build and run! Xcode will automatically pick the ad hoc provisioning profile created (named "XC Ad Hoc: xxx") which includes all your devices. You can check it at the Member Center at developer.apple.com as well.

I had the exact same problem and the above worked. Xcode version 6.4.